# save as very slow in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 in 4 PC's 
I face a peculiar problem in all of them: 
I have a USB stick with about 13000 libreoffice writer archives. When trying to rename one of them with "save as", it takes a long time before I am able to type the new name. And if I regret and type a new name before saving it, it again takes a long time. In this interval , system monitor shows that my processor is very busy. It appears that the system tries to sort all these archives  before saving the name (and If I change the name before saving, it starts sorting again). I tried abiword instead of libreoffice, the problem persists. I also tried to install pcmanfm but the problem persists too, it is not related to nautilus. 
Could anybody help ? It is a big big trouble for me. 
Thanks in advance